# Sensor using X10 power line protocol connection to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, mesh-networks

I'm on connecting my Raspberry Pi 3B board with [X10 EagleEye Motion Sensor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/X10-EagleEye-Motion-Sensor-Indoor-Outdoor-MS14A-New-No-Box-30-day-Warranty-/282373088489?_trksid=p2349526.m2548.l4275) using [X-10 CM11A ActiveHome](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VQZ62RS) Serial interface.

Can anybody share a library(C/C++, Java, Python) or open source tool used to control [X10 power line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_(industry_standard)) sensors with  X-10 CM11A and Raspberry Pi?

Comment: HA is essentially based on python, so it would seem the logical choice for integration work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HEYU](http://www.heyu.org/) is a text-based console program for remotely controlling lights and appliances in the home or office.   The complete source is made available under the GNU GPLv3 license.

Heyu uses the CM11A computer interface to send and receive X10 control signals over the AC power lines to modules which can turn On, Off, or Dim attached lamps or appliances.   It can store a schedule of timed events in the CM11A memory for execution when the computer is turned off or disconnected.

Heyu supports an optional W800RF32A, MR26A, or RFXCOM RF receiver connected to a second port as an auxiliary input device for RF signals from X10 and other supported transmitters.

Heyu can also use an optional CM17A interface to transmit X10 RF signals.

Thanks to tutorials by [Corey Murnaghan](http://coreyswrite.com/tips-tricks/amazon-echo-x10-home-control/), I was able to integrate my existing elaborate x10 home lighting system with Amazon Voice Control. A Raspberry Pi running Heyu, the ha-bridge, and a Firecracker CM17A interface works beautifully with my Amazon Alexa Dot control my X10 devices.

Answer (score 4):

I had an Ubuntu system with X10, CM11A, and heyu for several years and switched it all over to a Raspberry Pi about 4 years ago.
I then replicated it twice for my parents, and a sibling.

It can be a pain to get it all working, but once it does, it's great.

I have Python scripts that follow the heyu log files to generate alarms.
Other scripts use heyu for control.

Comment: So your suggestion is using heyu via python?